# Make one column of a Bootstrap row scrollable

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to figure out how/where to place the overflow: scroll style to a bootstrap div element with no luck.  My application is angularjs talking to a local MySQL server...so not easy to put up a jsfiddle of it...I will try to attach a picture and some code and hopefully someone can steer me in the right direction.

My goal is to have a master list of songs on the left hand side which now has about 100 songs.  Then I have three setlists to the right that I drag songs into to build out the sets.  This all works ok using JQuery sortable stuff.  My issue now is that the master songlist needs to scroll down to reach all songs while the setlists stay on the screen.

In the image attached the Bootstrap container is outlined in blue, the row in dashed red, the column in dashed green and finally the #masterList and #setxx DIVs are in solid red.

It looks like I have the scroll bar inside the right DIV of elements...but the page seems to render the entire list so the scroll happens at the browser level...and not within the DIV.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ER

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">  <!-- Master song list DIV !-->     
            <div ng-controller="getMasterSongListController">
            <b>Song Master List</b>
              <div id="masterList" style="overflow: scroll;">
                  <div id="songID_{{song.ID}}" ng-repeat="song in songs | orderBy:'ID'" class="item">
                    {{song.ID}} - {{song.Title}}
                  </div>
              </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">  <!-- Set one DIV !-->
          <div ng-controller="getSongsSetOneController">
            <b>SET 01</b>
              <div id="setOne">
                  <div id="songID_{{song.ID}}" ng-repeat="song in setOneSongs" class="item">
                    {{song.ID}} - {{song.Title}}
                  </div>
              </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">  <!-- Set two DIV !-->
          <div ng-controller="getSongsSetTwoController">
            <b>SET 02</b>
              <div id="setTwo">
                  <div id="songID_{{song.ID}}" ng-repeat="song in setTwoSongs" class="item">
                    {{song.ID}} - {{song.Title}}
                  </div>
              </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">  <!-- Set three DIV !-->
          <div ng-controller="getSongsSetThreeController">
            <b>SET 03</b>
              <div id="setThree">
                  <div id="songID_{{song.ID}}" ng-repeat="song in setThreeSongs" class="item">
                    {{song.ID}} - {{song.Title}}
                  </div>
              </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Screenshot of Set List Maker Application

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you want something like this?

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container-fluid {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.left,
.right {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.right {
  background-color: khaki;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-3 left">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I have seen this code and have been trying to assimilate it into mine.  I have tried giving my mastersonglist an ID tag of "#left" to try to make it work ...but it has not.  If I paste in teh DIV info from this snippet to the front of my HTML I can see the left and right panes with scroll bars overlaid on top of my Bootstrap containers...if I paste the DIVs at the bottom of my HTML page, all the BS stuff is gone and the left/right panes are there with greyed out scroll bars.  I will remove all my code and HTML, start over with this example and start adding in my elements.

Comment: It seems that adding the "position: absolute" to the DIV 'breaks' things in my Bootstrap grid.  If I use the example provided...and try to put those div tags in a container it doesn't really do anything with the position: absolute in play ...if I remove position:absolute the DIV pops into the container...but the scroll turns off and goes grey...

Comment: Hi i've updated my answer try to give both divs fixed height of 100vh or 800px or something.

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect.  The only minor thing (not sure how 100vh works) ... there was one last song at the bottom of the list that I could not get to so I made it 90vh and that was perfect.  Maybe there was a little real estate at the bottom of the page that needed accounting for..not sure...but it works great thank you!!

Comment: VH = viewport height, but instead of vh you can give it a fixed height of lets say 900px.